# Multiple mysql query combining to make json object

Tags: php, json

I have a problem regarding multiple mysql queries and json object. I have 2 tables as

## user_table

1. user_id
2. user_name
3. user_fullname
4. user_email

## user_contact

1. sender
2. receiver
3. approve

I am getting contact list from second table with description from first table. Where the concept is defined in mysql query below.(i.e. a user wants to list all his contact details(with description from user_table) where sender is the user himself or receiver is the user with approve 1.)

Main task is to retun json object like

```
{"contact":[{"user_name":"name1","user_fullname":"Fullname","user_email":"example@example.com","approve":"1"},{"user_name":"name2","user_fullname":"Fullname2","user_email":"example2@example.com","approve":"0"}]}
```

I need to combine two tables. so far I did is writing this ,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_contact` WHERE `adder` = $user_id  OR (`receiver` = $user_id AND `approve` = 1)");
$rows = array();
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0){
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
             $rows[] = $r;
            }
            echo json_encode(array('contact' => $rows));  
        }else{
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "You do not have any Contact so far. ";
            echo json_encode($response); 
        }
```

The above code returns json data from one table only. How can I obtain the json as mentioned above combining two tables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: either write a `JOIN` query that selects from both tables, or run two separate queries, stuff the data into your `$row[]` array, then encode that.

Comment: could you please give me some example.

Comment: do exactly what you're doing now, just run two `while() { $row[] = ...}` type code blocks. If you need to keep the data from the tables separate, then use `$row['table1'][] = ...` and `$row['table2'][] = ...`

Comment: well I user following `select user_table.user_name from user_table where (select user_contact.receiver FROM user_contact WHERE (user_contact.adder = 123454 OR (receiver = 123454 AND approve = 1)))`. But it is now working, I got sql error . To be straight I am not a good sql writer.